# How can I redirect to different file extension via htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess

How can I redirect all the visitors to a different file extension. Example:
Visitor trying to access: http://www.anywebsite.com/0001.jpeg but redirect to http://www.anywebsite.com/0001.pdf. There are thousands of files in one directory with such redirect. How can i redirect all files using a single code in .htaccess ??

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a possible duplicate question but you can find it easily via search

```
# change file extensions
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).jpeg$ http://domain.tld/$1.pdf [R=301,L]
```

Review this link for further explanation: 
https://htaccessbook.com/add-remove-change-file-extensions-htaccess/